# Splitting the sum of several datasets

Tags: gooddata

My workspace has several datasets; specifically dataset 1 and dataset 2. Each dataset has a dollar value fact that I’m plotting. My aim is to make an insight that splits the sum of dataset 1 value and dataset 2 value. Is it possible to create such an insight directly in GoodData, or does my model need to calculate the totals outside of GoodData and inport into another dataset?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to sum two facts from different datasets, but don't forget to make sure your Logical Data Model (LDM) structure allows you to do so, i.e., both datasets must be connected/referenced correctly. Please check [Connection Points in Logical Data Models](https://help.gooddata.com/doc/enterprise/en/data-integration/data-modeling-in-gooddata/logical-data-model-components-in-gooddata/connection-points-in-logical-data-models). Once you do this, you will need to create a slightly complex metric that may look as follows:

> SELECT SUM (Fact1 + Fact2)

You could then reference this metric in a compound metric, for example:

> SELECT FactsSum / Revenue_Last_Year